# Unable to run Flutter app - Unsupported gradle project

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run my flutter app. However when I try to run my app I get an error that I can not find anything about

C:\Users\Larson Carter\Desktop\kamino-master (1)>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A6013 in debug mode...
[!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by
running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to
the new project.

I'm running the latest version of android studio, flutter, dart and my packages are up to date. And I still can not find a solution.

Comment: Could you please show your project folder structure?

Comment: @AlexKuzmin what do you mean by project folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

First You need to install flutter sdk..
Then initialize sdk in environmental variables.
Then Open Android Studio And give the path of flutter sdk and then create project/

Comment: I already Installed the flutter SDK. I have been using flutter for a few months now. I just had this error now happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check launch.json file
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}


Make sure using latest gradle. Check it in android -> gradle -> gradle-wrapper.properties file
```

[image: Check for how to open launch.json file]

Comment: Where can I find launch.json?

Comment: In VSCode Menu, Click on View ==> Command Palette  ==> Debug: Open launch.json. Updated with screenshot. please check it.

Comment: I'm not using VSCode I'm using android studio.